# Is it possible to decompose this expression?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

Is it possible to factorize 
$$(-\partial^2+\phi^2(r))^2-\left(\frac{\partial\phi(r)}{\partial r}\right)^2,$$
where $\phi(r)$ is a function of $r\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+\xi^2}$ and $\partial^2$ is the 4-dimensional Laplacian? Actually since we have the $SO(4)$ symmetry, we can separate the angular part and focus on the radial part. That is, we can take 
$$\partial^2\rightarrow \frac{1}{r^3}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^3\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\equiv \hat{L}(r)$$.
Note that we can not simply factorize it as
$$\left(-\hat{L}(r)+\phi^2(r)+\left(\frac{\partial\phi(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right)\cdot\left(-\hat{L}(r)+\phi^2(r)-\left(\frac{\partial\phi(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right)$$
because of the non-commutativity of derivative operators.
Here I just wonder whether there is a subject that show us how to factorize operator polynomials systematically?

If it can not be factorized, can anyone give a proof?

Comment: What does the term $-\partial^2$ stand for? Is it second order derivative operator? With respect to what do we take derivative then?

Comment: @Vlad $\partial\equiv\partial_{x^i}$, where $x^i=x, y, z, \xi$.

Comment: Please go more into the definition of terms in that equation for those of us who might know how to factorize in general but not know enough about differential operators.  For example, is $\partial_{x^i} = $ the partial derivative operator, and why can you add the two terms above, like what space do they belong to?  Thank you!

Comment: Is there any more information about $\phi$ other than you can take a partial with respect to $r$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi^2(r)$, power or composition?

Comment: To prevent needless confusion, you want your $\partial^2 = \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{\partial }{\partial r } r^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial r}$, that is the radial piece of a Euclidean Laplacian in 4d?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, I modified the post now. Thanks for your comment.